# Real word for "equippable"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, is-it-a-word

*Equippable*, while not a really a word, seems to be accepted by the gaming community as a term for *this can be equipped*.  Is there a more appropriate word which is real, singular and essentially means the same? For example,

> I may pick the item up and carry it. However, whether I may put it in
>   my hand or not would be distinguished by whether it is **equippable**.

Comment: Must it be a single word? I think "*ready to equip*" seems the most natural.

Comment: Please clarify what makes you think that *equippable* is not a word. What is a "real" word anyway? If a word exists, is being used and understood by native speakers all over the world, is it not real? What is it then?

Comment: @RedDwight: A word is "real" to the extent that it is (a) understood and (b) accepted in any given context. Both of these criteria take a range of values and are not simply true/false. (a) Few people outside a narrow constituency would recognize the word, but would have to figure it out. As Monica notes, they would probably guess that it means that a person or thing is capble of being equipped, not that it is able to be used for the equipping. (B) If you tried to use this word in a college paper or an article for publication outside a gaming magazine, it might well be declared a non-word.

Comment: Why do you say **equippable** is not really a word?  It can mean "able to be equipped with devices that extend functionality".  https://www.google.com/search?q=equippable&newwindow=1&sca_esv=594424414&rlz=1CATMUU_enUS1067&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKmMjPbGNJlb6481t4k3f8AD95ySeA:1703853163071&source=lnt&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1900,cd_max:1999&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiP5KLU07SDAxXLlIkEHTj6BT0QpwV6BAgWEBU&biw=1349&bih=631&dpr=1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Long-time gamer here and I'd go with [*carriable*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/carriable):

> Able to be carried; portable.

It's expected that if you can carry an item, you can use it "on the go."

Also remember that considering language is a communication system of which the primary aim is to understand each other, you still can use *equippable*. If the listener clearly understands what you mean, the purpose of language is fulfilled and no "law" has been broken :)

Comment: I'm already using something very similar for that purpose, *attainable*.  I need to differentiate between being able to have something in your possession, and being able to equip that item.

Answer (score 9):

I think the word you want is *usable*.  The weapon (or scroll or potion or...) *is usable* or *can be equpped* or *is equippable* (the usage you're trying to replace).

Caution: the gaming world uses words like "equip" in a way that's somewhat counter to other contexts, which is part of what causes the confusion here.  Gamers say that the *object* of the operation is "equippable", while others refer to the *thing being equipped* as being "equippable".  For example, a car can be equipped with snow tires, but we would never say that the *tires* are "equippable".  If anything is it's the car.

Comment: "Usable" sounds like the answer to me. Is the OP looking for something more specific, like that it is usable for some specific purpose?

Comment: *Usable* does not sound like the answer to me.  *Equippable* and *usable* are two different things.  Sure, they usually go hand in hand, but they don't mean the same thing.

Comment: This isn't a synonym. Scrolls are usable but not equippable, since they are held in the inventory until consumed, not put in an armor slot. Armor that weighs 1000 pounds is equippable but not usable, since your character will be crawling instead of running.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go with "No", that is, there is not a 'real' word that is more appropriate for your desired usage.

*Equippable*, despite not appearing in a dictionary under its own entry, is perfectly understandable, consisting of a well-known root plus a well-known suffix which fits the root just fine.  There will not be any confusion caused by its usage.  Go with it.

Answer (score 0):

Granted the context you provide, *moddable* seems to be an established modifier. I'm not understanding the relevance of the example you cite though, as it contains neither the word *equippable* nor any combination of words carrying its weight of meaning. Beyond that, the words *expandable* and *upgradeable* seem fine. It would be helpful however to have a very particular sentence to work with.

Comment: updated with some context.

Comment: Oh my. That changes things exponentially.

Comment: So far, _transportable_ seems to do. But do you mean, (I mean really), to think of the item as something which can be _made to be portable_, if only, that is, it were _xxxx_ (where _xxxx_ is the word you're asking for)? ...which is to say that the item, by design, would easily allow itself to be physically modified in order to _become_ portable?

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to equipment and how it can be configured, I would recommend "configurable."

> I may pick the item up and carry it. However, whether I may put it in my hand or not would be distinguished by whether it is equippable.

However, if you are referring to whether it can be put in your hand (as opposed to portable in some other fashion, like slung over the shoulder), I would recommend "hand-operated".

What you mean by "put in my hand" could have a bearing on what you are looking for. (E.g., A car in the wrong hands can be a dangerous weapon.)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations:
strap-able,
equip-able,
attachable,
wield-able

Equip to a gamer means;

*"*A character's ability to make an item in their possession 'active' or 'ready for use' by occupying one of several 'slots' that represent the character's active items on a graphical user interface(GUI) un-equipping an item would be removing it from active duty and placing it back in your backpack or other form of storage."*

When you think of equip in that sense you can see why other words will not work.

here is an example:

http://www.diablowiki.net/images/thumb/d/d9/Inv-comparison-aug-2010.jpg/500px-Inv-comparison-aug-2010.jpg

Items on the player are equipped items on the bottom portion are un-equipped

Answer (score 0):

i feel like most of you are arguing over whether or not using made up words that are universally understood is proper or not and not answering the question.

i had the same problem as the author of this topic and ultimately need a word that is synonymous with equippable *and is accepted by spellcheck*

I am going with **attachable** or **wieldable**.

Comment: AIUI, "Wieldable" is limited specifically to weapons (or maybe hand items like tools, magic wands, etc), whereas "equippable" also works for armor and accessories.